# Using transforms correctly

Tags: javafx

In the following code I am trying to make a hexagon using points I derived by hand for the unit hex and then I would like to scale it up. However, it does not work. Instead of of a white hex with a green border I get a solid green hex. Am I misunderstanding the effect of the transformation Scale? It seems to start with the unit hex and paint out all the way to the scaled out hex, thus the color. Or is that again a misunderstanding?

How do I get a scalable shape with border width X and desired color fill?

```
Polygon {
     points: [1, 0, 0.5, -0.866, -0.5, -0.866, -1, 0, -0.5, 0.866, 0.5, 0.866]
     fill: Color.WHITE
     translateX: 100
     translateY: 100
     strokeWidth: 2
     transforms: Scale {x: 20, y: 20}
     stroke: Color.GREEN
     opacity: 0.3
}
```

Comment: I have noticed that that the transformation affects the path so that if stroke width is 1 then there is a small white interior. the question still stands though. I find this behavior bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be you're setting the `strokeWidth` to 2.

The strokeWidth is applied BEFORE the scaling transformation, so you have a unit hex with a strokeWidth of 2, which completely obscures the white hex at the center.  This obscured (and apparently solid green) hex is then scaled up 20 times...producing a larger green hex.

Try setting the strokeWidth lower, like this:

```
Polygon {
            points: [1, 0, 0.5,  - 0.866,  - 0.5,  - 0.866,  - 1, 0,  - 0.5, 0.866, 0.5, 0.866]
            fill: Color.WHITE
            translateX: 100
            translateY: 100
            strokeWidth: 0.5
            transforms: Scale {x: 20, y: 20}
            stroke: Color.GREEN
            opacity: 0.3
        }
```

and you should see the white hex with a green border.  Continue reducing the strokeWidth until you get the desired results.

Comment: Seems like it should be otherwise.